# bxSlider onSlideBefore - Doesn't work after first pass through

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider

I'm working on a slideshow using bxSlider and the onSlideBefore callback. While it works on the first iteration of the slider, the function fails on subsequent visits to a specific slide, or on the second (and on) iteration through the slides.

Here's the code in question:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var slider = $('.slider').bxSlider({
        auto:true,
        mode: 'fade',
    pause:8000,
    captions:false,
    controls:true,
    onSliderLoad: function(){
        var caption = $('#0 .caption').contents();              
        $(".imageCaption").html(caption);
            },  
        onSlideBefore: function(){
            var caption = '#';
            caption += slider.getCurrentSlide();
        caption += ' .caption';
        var cap = $(caption).contents();
        $(".imageCaption").html(cap);
        },
        }); 
});
```

[Example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w5bQM/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially what was happening was jQuery was pulling the contents out of Div A and placing it in Div B.

I wanted it to be copied, but retained in Div A. By replacing `.contents()` with `.html()` I fixed my issue.